# Porting Oracle NVL to Postgres Coalesce fails

Tags: postgresql-9.2

I'm porting old Oracle code to PostgreSQL 9.2.  There are hundreds of calls to Oracle NVL(), so I created mapping functions to provide the equivalent functionality.  This one should be trivial, but is failing for reasons not at all obvious to me.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION nvl(expr1 text, expr2 text)
  RETURNS text AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  RETURN COALESCE( expr1, expr2 );
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT IMMUTABLE;
```

I have variants of NVL defined for different input parameter types, but for testing, I've deleted all but this one.  I'm sure this one is being called because if I delete it, I get an unknown function error.

Here are the results of several queries on this database illustrating the problem.

```sql
# select nvl(null, 'N/A');
 nvl 
-----

(1 row)

# select coalesce(nvl(null, 'N/A'), 'ITS STILL NULL???');
     coalesce      
-------------------
 ITS STILL NULL???
(1 row)
```

From the above, I can see that coalesce works fine stand alone, but not in my function.

I'm using a very recent version of PostgreSQL:

```sql
# select version();
PostgreSQL 9.2.4 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120
313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3), 64-bit
```

Any clues?

Comment: You might want to check out orafce (https://github.com/orafce/orafce).

Comment: Your example works fine for me.

Comment: Thanks @PeterEisentraut.  The fact that it worked for you made me ask if I had done anything at all differently and I discovered that my actual function definition had STRICT on it which is what caused it not to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that my function had **STRICT** IMMUTABLE on the end of the function definition.  I left that off of the original post, but have edited it to show those parameters.

STRICT causes the function to ALWAYS return null when one of the arguments is null. In this case, I don't want that because this function is expected to test for null internally and respond appropriately.

That's what I get for using cut and pasted code templates without fully understanding what they do.

Answer (score 3):

This trivial functions should be implemented in SQL language, when it is possible. You can get much better performance:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION nvl(expr1 text, expr2 text)
  RETURNS text AS
$BODY$
  SELECT coalesce($1, $2);
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql;
```

Comment: Problem is that `NVL` does not behave exactly has `COALESCE`.
`SELECT NVL('', NULL) FROM DUAL;` returns NULL in Oracle whereas `SELECT COALESCE('', NULL);` returns blanck in Postgres...

Comment: @SuperPoney, sure - this is another very common issue. But if you want to emulate Oracle's behaviour, then you need to do everywhere - not just in one function.